# Robot Framework Regex handling of returned value: None

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to match returned value `None` via regular expression.

```
*** Variables ***
${value_regex}   ^null$|^None$

*** Test Case ***
${response} =  Get Request  ${IP} ${api}
Log  ${response.json()}    #will return: {'debug': [{'name': 'Jim', 'value': None}], 'result': 0}
${value} =  Set Variable  ${response.json()['debug'][0]['value']}
Log  ${value}    #will return None
Should Match Regexp    ${value}    ${value_regex}
```

I got an error : `Arguments: [ None | '^null$|^None$' ] 
    TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Is there a way how to handle return value `None` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is the type of `${value}` - it is `None`, the python datatype/object, while the regexp check expects a string.
And it's such because the `.json()` method casts the different attributes to the corresponding types - string, integers, floats, None.

The simplest solution is to cast it to string before comparing it with a regexp:

```
${value}=    Convert To String    ${value}
Should Match Regexp    ${value}    ${value_regex}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Your solution fixed my problem.